# Balancing Equation of Octane in combustion Chamber

Tags: mechanical-engineering, chemistry

Hey guys I am trying to balance out the combustion equation for reactants: Octane + Air

with products: CO2, H2O, N2, and O2; and 120% oh excess air.

My balancing equation looks like this:

$$ C_8H_{18} + 1.2* a(O_2 + 3.76 N_2) \rightarrow bCO_2 +cH_2O + dO_2 + eN_2 $$

My approach was as follows:

C: $b = 8$

H: $2c = 18$

O: $2b + c + 2d = 2*1.2a $

N: $e = 3.76*1.2a$

However, I think somewhere in my steps there's something I am not doing correctly as I am unable to determine 'a' with the system of equations I tried developing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you also need to take into account that the complete burn for octane is:

$$2C_8H_{18} + 25\;O_2 \rightarrow 16\;CO_2 +18\;H_2O $$

Therefore $a$ should be equal to $\frac{25}{2}$.